# Javascript count between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 2 arrays objects and I need to do a count of home many types of card we have.

The first object contains all the car id's and the second list contains the types of cars.

Here is the data:

```
var arr = {
    "categories": [{
        "id": "100",
        "name": "category name",
        "car_id": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "192",
        "name": "category name here",
        "car_id": "25"      
    }, {
        "id": "192",
        "name": "category name here",
        "car_id": "27"      
    }]
};


var arr2 = {
    "cars": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "car name",
        "car_id": "1",
        "type": "ford"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name 2",
        "car_id": "25",
        "type": "ford"      
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name 2",
        "car_id": "27",
        "type": "fiat"      
    }]
};
```

There's only 5 types of cars so I have 5 variables:

```
var:

ford,
fiat,
mazda,
mini,
mg
```

So, what I need to end up with is something like this:

```
ford: 2;
fiat: 1;
mazda: 0;
mini: 0;
mg: 0;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is always a string.

Comment: rephrased the question

Comment: I'd use a for in loop and an object with keys as the car names and values as the counter. I think this is an easy enough task, you will want to figure it out yourself before relying on stack overflow

Comment: What does "home many types of card" mean?

Comment: How does the first array figure into the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your number of types are fixed, then try this approach

Make an map first

```
var map = {
  ford: 0,
  fiat: 0,
  mazda: 0,
  mini: 0,
  mg: 0
};
```

Now iterate the arrays and count by types

```
arr2.cars.forEach( function( item ){
  map[ item.type ]++; 
});
```

your map is populated with the values now.

```js
var arr2 = {
  "cars": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "car name",
    "car_id": "1",
    "type": "ford"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "name 2",
    "car_id": "25",
    "type": "ford"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "name 2",
    "car_id": "27",
    "type": "fiat"
  }]
};
var map = {
  ford: 0,
  fiat: 0,
  mazda: 0,
  mini: 0,
  mg: 0
};

arr2.cars.forEach(function(item) {
  map[item.type] ++;
});

console.log(map);
```

Comment: But by definition there will be other types, either now or in the future.

Comment: Since OP mentioned that there are 5 variables so I thought number of types are fixed. Anyways this can easily be extended to support dynamic number of types.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = {
    "categories": [{
        "id": "100",
        "name": "category name",
        "car_id": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "192",
        "name": "category name here",
        "car_id": "25"      
    }, {
        "id": "192",
        "name": "category name here",
        "car_id": "27"      
    }]
};

var arr2 = {
    "cars": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "car name",
        "car_id": "1",
        "type": "ford"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name 2",
        "car_id": "25",
        "type": "ford"      
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name 2",
        "car_id": "27",
        "type": "fiat"      
    }]
};

var carCount, typeCount;

arr.categories.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.hasOwnProperty("car_id")){
         carCount = arr.categories.length;
    }
});

arr2.cars.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.hasOwnProperty("type")){
         typeCount = arr2.cars.length;
    }
});

console.log(carCount);
console.log(typeCount);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Law7rzc2/

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is your go-to for this kind of array computation. A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will help you keep track of unique car makes as you iterate thru the array of cars.

```js
var obj2 = {
    "cars": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "car name",
        "car_id": "1",
        "type": "ford"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name 2",
        "car_id": "25",
        "type": "ford"      
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name 2",
        "car_id": "27",
        "type": "fiat"      
    }]
};

const typeStat = cars => {
  let map = cars.reduce((m, {type}) =>
    m.set(type, (m.get(type) || 0) + 1), new Map());
  return Array.from(map, ([make, count]) => ({make, count}));
};

let stats = typeStat(obj2.cars)

console.log(stats);
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "make": "ford",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "make": "fiat",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
countBy(arr2.cars, 'type')
```

The implementation of `countBy` is left as an exercise.